# Magento 2 Load More Product Script

Tags: magento2, products, ajax, category-products

I am using this script for Load More in Magento 2 But it's not working

```
 <script src ="https://infiniteajaxscroll.com/vendor/jquery-ias/dist/jquery-ias.min.js"></script>
<link src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ravbetsky/infinite-ajax-scroll/master/dist/css/jquery.ias.css"/>
     var ias = jQuery.ias({
    container:  ".test",
    item:       ".products-grid",
    pagination: ".pages-items li",
    next:       ".item a"
});
ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());            // shows a spinner (a.k.a. loader)
ias.extension(new IASTriggerExtension({offset: 3})); // shows a trigger after page 3
ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension({
  text: 'There are no more pages left to load.'      // override text when no pages left
}));
```

if I go to second scroll, the add to cart button is not working properly.

Please give me some script for Load More Products.

Comment: with this [Magento 2 Infinite Scroll](https://www.mageants.com/infinite-scroll-for-magento-2.html) extension will solve it you can use it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Dava Gordon has suggested i have been using the https://github.com/Strategery-Inc/Magento2-InfiniteScroll which does work however has the problem you are witnessing with ajax add to cart breaking after load.

This seems to be an issue with the **x-magento-init** scripts that run on page load and therefore do not run on ajax requests. To fix this issue however i recommend adding a single line of code to:

> **Strategery/Infinitescroll/view/frontend/web/js/infinitescroll.js**

```
$("form[data-role='tocart-form']").catalogAddToCart();
```

This goes at about **line 91** so the on rendered event updates the magento add to cart forms to allow for ajax add to cart.

Section of code should therefore be updated to look like below:

```
window.ias.on('rendered', function(items){
                SgyIAS._log({eventName: 'render', items: items});
                $("form[data-role='tocart-form']").catalogAddToCart();
            });
```

I have also created a pull request on the github page for this issue and fix so can also be seen on there now.

Comment: Have you done this as a pull request on the extension?  Might help improve it without people having to overwrite it / or mod it :)

Comment: TBH i just did this in last few mins will think about adding it to github soon

Comment: Ok think ive created a pull request for this now.

Comment: Where i need to add this

Comment: I added but no luck

Comment: @Kothari Have you checked the script is updated, run setup:upgrade and deploy ect? I have tested this and it worked for me.

Comment: The infinitescroll.js script may be cached or something i would check that it is updated by looking at sources to see that the change is there.

Comment: Its on github now: https://github.com/harrigo/Magento2-InfiniteScroll.git

Comment: Also i find that the js files are often cached client site which will need clearing also.

Comment: I am using this updated extension on every page 1 product only ajax working rest of the product add to cart request itself not going

Comment: Can you check the infinitescroll.js in browser has actually got the change present? Search infinitescroll.js in developer tools and open and check that line of code as i may have made mistake on the github page as when i downloaded it change wasn't there i think ive sorted this now. Also are there any errors in console? Other than that maybe add alert("Updated"); in js right after line of code we added and check that it is firing at right time after new products rendered.

Comment: Also make sure you have cleared all cache on web browser. In chrome i open dev tools and then long click refresh you are then given an option to clear cache. You can also disable cache when dev tools is open which is handy. I updated this on 2 stores and each time it didnt work until i did above.

Comment: using this  $("form[data-role='tocart-form']").catalogAddToCart(); for ajax addtocart but it is throwing error $(..).catalogAddToCart is not function

Any solution for this

Comment: @harri, it's not working for me, Products are loading after scroll but URL is changing with parameters, can we avoid that?

Comment: @jafarpinjar Not sure of your exact problem seems different to this question which is about ajax add to carts with infinite scroll. Yeah i'm sure you can change that it's probably some javascript somewhere in the module that sets the url. Are these parameter for pages or something?

Comment: @harri, here is my question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260414/how-to-re-init-ajax-add-to-cart-inside-the-response-in-magento2

Answer (score 2):

This module is not worth supporting can i recommend you use https://github.com/Strategery-Inc/Magento2-InfiniteScroll which does work

Comment: I tried that also No luck

Comment: @Kothari whats the error message you get?

Comment: No error if i cick add to cart it redirect the page

Comment: Is it a configurable product your trying to add to basket? or is it a simple if its a configurable then this is the way it is supposed to work as you must update the options, if you can send us any errors in your console it would help a lot

Comment: even simple products also it redirect

Comment: I have the same issue the ajax add to cart only works for products prior to being added by inifinite scroll, i'm looking into this.

Comment: @DavaGordon, this will add the parameters in URL, can we avoid that?

Comment: @jafarpinjarim im sure there is a setting for that on this module

Answer (score 1):

Check this [free extension](http://magento-development.medma.net/lazy-load-products.html) and see if it works for you.
(It worked fine for me)

Comment: If I goto second scroll and click add to cart it reload the page

Comment: Well atleast it's in working condition and doesn't redirect to product description page.

Comment: @VivekKumar, your mentioned link is not working.

Answer (score 0):

"data" get response of next page, you need to update next page add to cart button with "[data-role=tocart-form]"

```
     jQuery.ajax({
                url: getUrl,
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                }).done(function (data) {

                var htmlObject=jQuery(".products.wrapper:last").after(data.productdata);

                htmlObject.find('[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout')
                            .attr('data-mage-init', JSON.stringify({'catalogAddToCart': {}}));
                            htmlObject.trigger('contentUpdated');


            });
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: getUrl is not defined what i need to add getUrl

Comment: For "getUrl" you need to set your Ajax url, where you want to call your Ajax request. 
and update code

Comment: main thing is you need to update your response data.

Answer (score 0):

Something else to bare in mind if you have JS set to merge in production you will get errors with ias not defined so make sure you do the following in a child theme etc/view.xml

`<exclude>
  <item type="file">Strategery_Infinitescroll::js/infinitescroll.js</item>
       <item type="file">Strategery_Infinitescroll::js/jquery-ias.js</item>
</exclude>`