# Magento 2 add to cart with ajax is not working for infinite scroll

Tags: magento2, ajaxaddtocart

I have the infinite scroll module. This removes the pagination on category pages, and shows a button, when clicked loads more products.

The ajax add to cart is not working properly,  only for the first items that are loaded (the first page in this case). When I press the button load more, new products are coming (so this is now the page 2), but for these products the add to cart with ajax is not working, it refreshes the page instead and after that the product is added to cart.

Now the link is changed, and now  I can  add again with ajax products on cart for page 2. So the link is changed  it is, for example , `loremipsum.com/categoryname?p=2&_=1510315834548` something like that.

If I press now the load more button, it should be page 3, but again the link doesn't change, it's the one with `?p=2` and if I add a product to cart, from the ones that belong to page 3, ajax add to cart not working, the page is loading again and the link change with `?p=3`. And so on

If I don't add anything in the cart and only press the load button over and over, the link remains without the pagination something like:  `loremipsum.com/categoryname`

So I think the problem is because the link doesn't have the page that was loaded, and only after the refresh it's added and the ajax add to cart is working for the products that belong to the page in the link.

**I should add custom js code to `init.phtml` file when the module ajax loads completely. But don't know what exactly. Does anybody knows how to make this work?**

This is the `init.phtml` file

```
<?php  
$helper = $this->helper('Lof\AjaxScroll\Helper\Data'); 
$productListMode = $block->getProductListMode(); 
$enable = $block->isEnable(); 

if($helper->isEnabled() && $enable) { ?>  
<script>
    require(['jquery',
        'Lof_AjaxScroll/js/script'  
        ], function ($) {

            $('<?php echo $helper->getConfig('lofajaxscroll/selectors/toolbar') ?>').<?php echo $helper->getConfig('lofajaxscroll/design/hide_toolbar') ? 'hide' : 'show' ?>();
            windowLoadedFlag = false;
            window.onload = function () {
                windowLoadedFlag = true;
            };   
            var jQueryWaiter = function () {
                var functions = [];
                var timer = function() {
                    if( typeof window.jQuery != 'undefined') {
                        while (functions.length) {
                            functions.shift()(window.jQuery);
                        }
                    } else {
                        window.setTimeout(timer, 100);
                    }
                };
                timer();
                return {
                    execute: function(onJQueryReady) {
                        if (window.jQuery) {
                            onJQueryReady(window.jQuery);
                        } else {
                            functions.push(onJQueryReady);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }();

            window.SgyIAS = {
                debug: false,
                _log: function(object) { 
                    //console.log(object); 
                },
                init: function(){ 
                    jQuery(function($) {
                        var config = {
                            item: '<?php echo $productListMode == 'grid' ? $helper->getConfig('lofajaxscroll/selectors/grid_mode') : $helper->getConfig('lofajaxscroll/selectors/list_mode') ?>',
                            container : '<?php echo $helper->getConfig('lofajaxscroll/selectors/content') ?>',
                            next: '<?php echo $helper->getConfig('lofajaxscroll/selectors/next') ?>',
                            pagination: '<?php echo $helper->getConfig('lofajaxscroll/selectors/pagination') ?>',
                            parameter: '<?php echo $helper->getConfig('lofajaxscroll/instances/enable_parameter') ?>',
                            delay: 600,
                            negativeMargin: <?php echo (int) $helper->getConfig('lofajaxscroll/design/buffer') ?>,
                            history: {
                                prev: '.prev'
                            },
                            noneleft: {
                                text: '<?php echo $helper->jsQuoteEscape(__($helper->getConfigData('lofajaxscroll/design/done_text'))) ?>',
                                html: '<div class="ias-noneleft" style="text-align: center;">{text}</div>'
                            },
                            spinner: {
                                <?php if($block->getLoaderImage() !== false): ?>
                                src: '<?php echo $block->getLoaderImage(); ?>',
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            html: '<div class="ias-spinner" style="text-align: center;"><img style="display:inline" src="{src}"/> <?php echo $helper->jsQuoteEscape(__($helper->getConfigData('lofajaxscroll/design/loading_text'))); ?></div>'
                        },  
                        trigger: {
                            text: '<?php echo $helper->jsQuoteEscape(__($helper->getConfigData('lofajaxscroll/design/load_more_text'))) ?>',
                            html: '<div class="ias-trigger ias-trigger-next" style="text-align: center; cursor: pointer;"><a>{text}</a></div>',
                            textPrev: '<?php echo $helper->jsQuoteEscape(__($helper->getConfigData('lofajaxscroll/design/load_more_text'))) ?>',
                            htmlPrev: '<div class="ias-trigger ias-trigger-prev" style="text-align: center; cursor: pointer;"><a>{text}</a></div>',
                            offset: <?php echo (int) $helper->getConfigData('lofajaxscroll/design/load_more') ?>
                        }

                    };


                    if (window.ias_config){
                        $.extend(config, window.ias_config);
                    }


                    SgyIAS._log({extension: 'ias', config: config});
                    window.ias = $.ias(config);

                    SgyIAS._log({extension: 'paging'});
                    window.ias.extension(new IASPagingExtension());

                    SgyIAS._log({extension: 'spinner'});
                    window.ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension(config.spinner));

                    SgyIAS._log({extension: 'noneleft'});
                    window.ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension(config.noneleft));

                    SgyIAS._log({extension: 'trigger'});
                    window.ias.extension(new IASTriggerExtension(config.trigger));  

                        // debug events
                        window.ias.on('scroll', function(scrollOffset, scrollThreshold){
                            SgyIAS._log({eventName: 'scroll', scrollOffset: scrollOffset, scrollThreshold: scrollThreshold});
                        });
                        window.ias.on('load', function(event){
                            SgyIAS._log({eventName:'load', event: event});
                        });
                        window.ias.on('loaded', function(data, items){
                            SgyIAS._log({eventName: 'loaded', data: data, items: items});
                        });
                        window.ias.on('render', function(items){
                            SgyIAS._log({eventName: 'render', items: items});
                            if (typeof($(items).find('.lof-lazy').lazy) === 'function') {
                                $(items).find('.lof-lazy').lazy({
                                    bind: "event",
                                    delay: 0
                                });


                                // add code here  working ajax add to cart after load more button is pressed


                            }
                        }); 
                        window.ias.on('noneLeft', function(){
                            SgyIAS._log({eventName: 'noneLeft'});
                        });
                        window.ias.on('next', function(url){
                            SgyIAS._log({eventName: 'next', url: url});
                        });
                        window.ias.on('ready', function(){
                            SgyIAS._log({eventName: 'ready'});
                        });
                        if(windowLoadedFlag){
                            $(window).load();
                        }

                        SgyIAS._log('Done loading IAS.');

                    });

                }
            };
            jQueryWaiter.execute(function(){
                SgyIAS.init();

            });
        });


//]]>
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

The custom code should be added where that comment is

Comment: hi @Raluca, got the solution, I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is already solved in [Magento 2 Load More Product Script](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184659/magento-2-load-more-product-script/)

You can directly use the fixed module available here - https://github.com/harrigo/Magento2-InfiniteScroll

Comment: hi @Vivek, there the third party module is different, here it is Lof module, can you provide fix for this extension please?

Comment: @jafarpinjar the extension I've provided is also free and user almost same logic, even works with 2.3. I suggest you use that instead.

Comment: I have tested the parent module https://github.com/Strategery-Inc/Magento2-InfiniteScroll

Comment: hi @Vivek Kumar, We have done almost all design and other things for this extension, can you please provide me the fix for this module

Comment: Also this module i installed and checked , its not working for me

Comment: adminhtml files are missing in GitHub, after installing above extension, I can't see any configuration in admin related to this module

Comment: hi @Vivek, this extension not working properly, Load more items are not loading

Comment: I hope I have installed layered navigation, so may be conflict with that issue

Comment: Please confirm you've properly configured the extension by matching it to config.xml

Comment: you can update here, i have created separate question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261738/conflict-in-layer-navigation-and-infinite-scroll-extension-magento2