# Conflict in layer navigation and infinite scroll extension magento2

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, product-list, infinte-scroll

I have Installed above BSS_layeredNavigation & Lof_Ajaxscroll extensions.

Both of them are working fine if used individually.

If both extensions are enabled there is a conflict.

To avoid conflict i used sequence in etc/module.xml like below.

```
 <sequence>       
    <module name="Lof_AjaxScroll"/>
  </sequence>
```

Still the problem exist. Infinite scroll are loading the items even after filter is applied on the left navigation.

**Example:**

I have Color = Red(2), Once filter is applied it is loading 2 items then Infinite scroll load all remaining items. This is not correct.

I have checked with the extension providers, Both of them are not coming forward to resolve this issue. Suggesting me to avoid other extension.

How to resolve this issue. Please, anyone, look into this and update me your ideas. Thanks

Comment: Still not sure what is meant here sorry. Not sure what you mean by add to cart is reinitialized. So all items are loading again?

Comment: I am struggling to understand. I think might be worth getting in touch with the vendors and getting a real fix in place for the issues as I do not have a copy of that module.

Comment: @harri, still you are not clear about the issue?, give me your skype id, let me explain in detail

Comment: @harri, Are you cleared with the issue now?

Comment: @jafarpinjar if you think that there is a module conflict, you can disable a module using "php bin/magento mo:d Vendor_Module" and test out things.

Comment: @VivekKumar, yes if disabled any module that works fine, but if both enabled only the problem occurs. I have posted like that only in the question, I need both the modules enabled and problem has to be resolved, Looking for it

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply, in case you still have similar issues: if you have a conflict, adding the sequence is not enough, you also have to fix the conflict. The conflict is there because both modules are trying to extend/rewrite the same magento class. So you find the class that is throwing the conflict, then change one the module to extend not the magento class anymore but the class of the other module. So for example:

- you have module P and module Q
- both have a Layer.php class that extends/rewrites magento Layer.php class
- In your sequence, you decide that module P has to load after module Q
- so you change P/Layer.php to extend/rewrite Q/Layer.php instead of Magento/Layer.php

Let me know if it is not clear